# How do I use Kindle Fire Tor App?

Tags: help

I have downloaded and opened Tor, and it goes into the app but it says I am not using Tor and won't let me access Tor, so how do I fix this so I can use it?

Comment: Specifically which app are you trying to use? Orbot, or something else? (I don't believe there's an officially supported Tor browser app.)

Comment: You need to look at how to configure Tor, its really easy and there are plenty of online tutorials mate.